# How "npm update" command works?

Tags: node.js, npm

I got 3 dependencies on my project, when I run `npm update` it doesn't update the version of one dependency (axios).
Here is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.26.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
  }
}
```

When I enter the `npm update` or `npm update --save` command, this is my actual result:

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

As I can see, the `axios` package doesn't get updated.
My expected result is to get the axios package at version 0.27.2 (latest at this day).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004)

> **Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4**
>
> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero element in the `[major, minor, patch]` tuple.

Since your `axios` dependency is defined as `^0.25.0`, with its minor version `25` being the left-most non-zero element, it will allow update to `0.25.X`, but not to `0.27.0`.

Either change the dependency in your package.json, or let `npm` do it. This should install the newest version:

```
npm install axios@* --save
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `npm update -d` or `npm update --save-dev` to update developer dependencies. (Dependencies used in development) Using `npm update` only would ignore the dev dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the command `npm install axios` and it will automatically `update axios` in your package.json